# Explode components recursively to get total value

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

*TL-TR:* I want to get the total value of a final item that is made of others, from which I have the buying price. Problem is semi-finished items.

Consider three types of items:

- **Final item:** It's made from raw items and/or semifinished items. These are the ones I want to get the total value.
- **Semifinished item:** It's made from raw items and/or semifinished items.
- **Raw item:** I have the cost of a unit of these ones.

A final item can be made, amongst other things, of a semifinished item which can be made, amongst other things, of another semifinished item and so on... on an **undeterminate** number of levels, until you get to all being raw items.

I know how to do this on C# but I'm interested on a pure SQL solution, that I believe is doable.

SQL Fiddle provided here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/138c3

And this is as far as I can get with the query...

```
SELECT BOM.output, SUM(P.price * BOM.quantity) as Total
FROM BOM
INNER JOIN 
Prices P ON P.input = BOM.Input
GROUP BY BOM.output
```

But of course that doesn't take semifinished prices into the sum as they don't exist in prices table.

**EDIT:** Another attempt, but it gives an error that grouping is not allowed in recursive queries.

```
WITH cte_table AS (
SELECT BOM.output, SUM(P.price * BOM.quantity) as Total
FROM BOM
INNER JOIN 
Prices P ON P.input = BOM.Input
GROUP BY BOM.output

UNION ALL
SELECT BOM.output, SUM(ISNULL(P.price,T.Total) * BOM.quantity) as Total
FROM BOM
LEFT JOIN 
Prices P ON P.input = BOM.Input
LEFT JOIN 
cte_table T ON T.output = BOM.Input
GROUP BY BOM.output
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_table
```

And some example of expected output (in light grey it must be calculated, in black is data):

[image: Example]

Comment: This is probably one of the most complete questions I have seen here in past few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the recursive query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/138c3/13)

**Query 1**:

```
with a as(
  SELECT BOM.output, BOM.input, P.price * BOM.quantity as price, 1 as level,
  convert(varchar(max), BOM.input) as path
  FROM BOM
  INNER JOIN 
  Prices P ON P.input = BOM.Input
  UNION ALL
  SELECT BOM.output, BOM.input, a.price * BOM.quantity as price, a.level + 1 as level,
  a.path + '/' + bom.input
  FROM a
  INNER JOIN BOM ON a.output = BOM.Input)
select output, sum(price) from a
group by output
-- select * from a
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/138c3/13/0)**:

```
| output |                   |
|--------|-------------------|
| Item 3 | 64.32000000000001 |
| Semi 1 |                63 |
| Semi 2 |              60.4 |
```